# How do I troubleshoot a Cisco MeetingPlace Express 1.1 fault, cannot join meeting?

Tags: cisco, flash

We have a Cisco MeetingPlace Express conference server, version 1.1. Logging in and scheduling meetings works, but Internet Explorer times out joining a meeting.

#### Client checks performed:

- Clients pass the browser test,
- Flash is working,
- pop-up blockers are off,
- the fault is the same in **Trusted Sites** and **Intranet** IE security zones.

#### Server checks performed:

- Full reboot,
- `mpx_sys restart`
- `mpx_app restart`

#### Interesting errors:

> `06/25 11:11:01:00 MAJ 1048780 exlog.cc 44 (90,0,0,0) sblob_dbs is 90% full`

There's an IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 10.00 database under all of this. Is the nearly-full "BLOB" DB causing the time-out?

#### Cisco MeetingPlace Express InfoCap

*Web Conference Debug Log Set*
`/opt/macromedia/breeze/logs/support/debug.log`

Notice all the slow queries,

```
[06-25 11:52:57] heck (d) SLOW QUERY: 429ms spid:23 com.macromedia.breeze.builder.Scheduler.getActiveHosts
[06-25 11:52:57] heck (d) SLOW QUERY: 253ms spid:23 com.macromedia.breeze.builder.Scheduler.updateExpiryDate
[06-25 11:52:58] w-24 (d) SLOW QUERY: 15056ms spid:26 com.macromedia.airspeed.dal.DAL.getUserSession
[06-25 11:53:03] w-22 (d) SLOW QUERY: 10941ms spid:51 com.macromedia.airspeed.dal.DAL.getUserSession
[06-25 11:53:11] w-22 (d) SLOW QUERY: 8725ms spid:51 com.macromedia.airspeed.dal.DAL.getUserSession
[06-25 11:53:16] w-22 (d) SLOW QUERY: 4255ms spid:51 com.macromedia.airspeed.db.DBConnection.update
[06-25 11:53:23] w-22 (d) SLOW QUERY: 7888ms spid:51 com.macromedia.airspeed.dal.DAL.getUserSession
```

I'm thinking that the fault is server-side. I'm grateful for any trouble-shooting tips for any of the products involved;

- Cisco MeetingPlace Express 1.1
- Macromedia Breeze
- IBM Informix Dynamic Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a clue...

### MPE : Breeze Web Conferencing becomes slow and unresponsive , Fixed CSCsr61095

> Symptom: Web Conferencing becomes slow and unresponsive.
>
> Conditions: Cisco Unified MeetingPlace Express 2.0(3.5)
>
> Workaround: Restart corrects the issue temporarily.
>
> Further Problem Description: Slow query messages can be seen in the logs. example: fgrep SLOW /opt/macromedia/breeze/logs/support/debug* Sample out put from cli [root@incredible logs]# fgrep SLOW /opt/macromedia/breeze/logs/support/debug* /opt/macromedia/breeze/logs/support/debug.log:[07-31 01:30:08] sche (d) SLOW QUERY: 545ms spid:24 c As the slow query messages build up the Breeze component eventually hangs and will require a restart to restore service.

Although in the question a restart doesn't help.